# Unable to add clutch fluid in my 1991 chevy S-10

Tags: chevrolet, clutch, s10, master-cylinder

When i go to add clutch fluid to my 91 chevy S-10 the rubber diaphram inside the cap forces the fluid right back out, most diaphrams ive seen can be collapsed with finger prior to screwing on cap but this one is thick rubber non collapsible any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! From what I'm seeing, your clutch master cylinder has a remote reservoir for it (ie: attached to the cylinder via a hose) ... is that correct? Looking on my favorite parts place online, I'm not seeing a reservoir offered. Realistically, you could get any remote reservoir and use that to feed the master. And no, the rubber should pop in and out, just like with a brake master reservoir.

Comment: One post on the S10 forum claims that he removed the rubber with no problem. I'm not making this an answer because it's just 3rd hand info: https://www.s10forum.com/threads/clutch-fluid-level-cap-gasket.475714/

Comment: @MTA and we know the rubber helps seal the reservoir, so would kind of be stupid to remove it without replacing it with some kind of seal. Otherwise water absorption occurs. Probably not as bad as with a brake system (less heat, for sure) ... boiling is probably not an issue.